# Use watch in store pattern

Tags: vue.js

Here is what I wanna do:
I have a component, one of its data is read from a shared object, and every time the value changed, I wanna know and do something about it. So I decided to use watch to that property. Here is my code looks like:

```
export default {                                          
data: function () {
  return {
    index: sharedData
  }
}, 
watch: {
  'index': function (val) {
       doSmething()
  }
} 
}
```

and my sharedData is very simple , just for demo:

```
let shatedData = {                                         
  testIndex: 0
}
```

Like the guide says , sharedData is an object.
But here comes the problem: the change of sharedData in this component, or event in other compoent, can be displayed correctly in index property, but the watch function is never fired(maybe I was listening to an object to change, but its structure is still the same).
So how can I do to let this component know that one specific shared data changed?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the same question on forum.vuejs.org, and get answer there, so I add the link to that answer here for anyone who may have the same question.
http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/4605/use-watch-in-store-pattern/3

Comment: you should mark this answer as "solved" too so users can see it immediatly.

Comment: Yes I tried, but I can only mark my own answer as solved in two days as stackoverflow ruled.

Comment: ah, I see. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ugly solution for my problem: add a computed property to listen to the exact property in that shared object.

```
computed: {                                                  
  compIndex: function () {
    console.log(`caught in computed value`)
    doSomething()
    return this.index.data
  }
},
```

This computed property must be stored in a hidden element so that the doSomething can be called.
Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer @ericchan1336 got on Vue forums copied here for reference:

the watch function is never fired because the index property itself never changes - it always contains the same object, only properties inside that object change.

For these cases, there's the deep: true option, which makes the watch inspect deep changes nested inside the watched property:

```js
watch: {
  'index': {
    deep: true,
    handler: function (val) {
       doSmething()
     }
   }
}
```